# Unable to show updated content using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to framework, MY objective is to show the recent content first but here when i refresh the page, the scrollbar is scrolling from top to bottom and showing recent content. Is it possible to show the recent one first rather than scrolling from top to bottom while refreshing.

Here is the code:

```
<Card>
  <CardHeader
    avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">S</Avatar>}
    title={
      <>
        <InputBase placeholder="Search Google Maps" margin="normal" />
        <IconButton type="submit" aria-label="search">
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </>
    }
  />
  <Divider />
  <CardContent style={{ overflow: "scroll" }} className={classes.contentHeight} id="chatList">
    <div>
      <Message isSender content="Hello" />
      {this.state.data.map((item) => {
        if (item.isSender) {
          return <Message isSender content={item.content} />;
        }
        return <Message content={item.content} />;
      })}
    </div>
    <div
      style={{ float: "left", clear: "both" }}
      ref={(list) => {
        this.messagesL = list;
      }}
    />
  </CardContent>
  <Divider />
  <CardActions>
    <Paper className={classes.contentPaper}>
      <Input margin="dense" className={classes.input} placeholder="Enter a Message" disableUnderline />
    </Paper>
  </CardActions>
</Card>;
```

Can anyone help me in this query? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scroll behavior to 'auto'.

```
scrollToBottom = () => {
  this.messagesL.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto" });
};
```

It's actually the default behavior, so can be omitted altogether.

```
scrollToBottom = () => {
  this.messagesL.scrollIntoView();
};
```

In previous projects I've allowed an options object to be passed so I can change the behavior when I want to:

```
scrollToBottom = options => {
  this.messagesL.scrollIntoView(options);
};
```

[scrollIntoView parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Parameters)